# How do I find the connectivity of a graph in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, graph-theory

I need to find the node/edge connectivity of a arbitrary graphs in Neo4j. That is, I want to find the minimum number of nodes OR edges that need to be removed in order to create 2 or more unconnected graphs. If the graph is already unconnected, a value of 0 works.

How do I do this?

Comment: [Hands-On: Connectivity Analytics in Neo4j With Cypher](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/big-data-graph-analytics/hands-on-connectivity-analytics-in-neo4j-with-cypher-H9w6T)?